# Android Call a method from another method

Tags: java, android, class

In my android app I have a View class that will activate on button click .. but I need to call another method it using an if else statement for that what I have to do...?

I checked

```
class name().execute();
```

for executing but it is only for the class... I am giving my code below..
In xml

```
android:onClick : "save"
```

In Activity

```
public void save(View V)
        {
            //code
    }
```

I need to call this method with if else statement

like

```
    SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            if (setting.getString("log", "").toString().equals("log")) 
           {

// call the above method

}









@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullexplanationentry_xm);

        SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        if (setting.getString("log", "").toString().equals("log")) 
       {
            //Here I need call the save method..

       }




        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
        EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText4);
        EditText et5 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText5);
        EditText et6 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText6);
        EditText et7 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText7);
        EditText et8 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText8);
        EditText et9 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText9);
        et1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett1"));
        et2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett2"));
        et3.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett3"));
        et4.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett4"));
        et5.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett5"));
        et6.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett6"));
        et7.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett7"));
        et8.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett8"));
        et9.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ett9"));



        db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDBI", MODE_PRIVATE, null);


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA (fname VARCHAR, mname VARCHAR,lname VARCHAR,cfname VARCHAR, cmname VARCHAR,clname VARCHAR,bday NUMERIC,bmonth NUMERIC,byear NUMERIC);");

         }



    public void save(View V)
    {

    long sum1 = 0;
    long sum2 = 0;
    long sum3 = 0;
    long sum7 = 0;
    long sum8 = 0;
    long sum9 = 0;
    sum10 = 0;
    sum11 = 0;
    sum12 = 0;
    sum13 = 0;
    long sum14 = 0;
    long sum15 = 0;
    long sum16 = 0;
    long sum17 = 0;
    sum18 = 0;
    sum19 = 0;
    sum20 = 0;
    long sum22 = 0;
    long sum23 = 0;
    long sum24 = 0;
    long sum25 = 0;
    sum70 = 0;
    sum80 = 0;
    sum90 = 0;
    //Destiny Number Karmic Debt
    long kar1 = 0;
    long kar2 = 0;
    long kar3 = 0;
    long kar7 = 0;
    //Heart Number Karmic Debt
    long kar4 = 0;
    long kar5 = 0;
    long kar6 = 0;
    long kar8 = 0;
    //Talent Number Karmic Debt
    //long kar9 = 0;
    long kar10 = 0;
    long kar11 = 0;
    //Personality Number Karmic Debt
    long kar12 = 0;
    long kar13 = 0;
    long kar14 = 0;
    long kar15 = 0;
    //Minor expression Number Karmic Debt
    long kar16 = 0;
    long kar17 = 0;
    long kar18 = 0;
    long kar19 = 0;

    //Minor Heart Desire Number Karmic Debt
    long kar20 = 0;
    long kar21 = 0;
    long kar22 = 0;
    long kar23 = 0;

    //Minor Personality Number Karmic Debt
    long kar24 = 0;
    long kar25 = 0;
    long kar26 = 0;
    long kar27 = 0;
    //Balance Number Karmic Debt
    long kar28 = 0;
    //year now to single digit
    long yearnow = 0;
    //month now to single digit
    long monthnow = 0;
    //Day now to single digit
    long daynow = 0;

    long ch = 0;
    long ch1 = 0;
    long ch2 = 0;
    long ch4 = 0;
    long ch3 = 0;
    long pin1 = 0;
    long pin2 = 0;
    long pin3 = 0;
    long pin4 = 0;
    long pin = 0;
    long br1 = 0;
    long br2 = 0;
    long br3 = 0;
    long a =0;

    int yearat =0;
    int monthat = 0;
    int dayat = 0;



    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    yearat = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    yearstr = Integer.toString(yearat);
    monthat = gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    monthstr = Integer.toString(monthat);
    dayat = gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    daystr = Integer.toString(dayat);




    List<Integer> sum21;


    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
    EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);

    EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText4);
    EditText et5 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText5);
    EditText et6 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText6);

    EditText et7 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText7);        
    EditText et8 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText8);
    EditText et9 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText9);






    sum1 = getSum1(et1.getText().toString());
    sum2 = getSum2(et2.getText().toString());
    sum3 = getSum3(et3.getText().toString());

    sum7 = getSum7(et7.getText().toString());
    sum8 = getSum8(et8.getText().toString());
    sum9 = getSum9(et9.getText().toString());

    sum11 = getSum11((et7.getText().toString()) + (et8.getText().toString()) + (et9.getText().toString()));
    sum12 = getSum12(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());

    sum13 = getSum13(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());
    sum14 = getSum14(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());
    sum15 = getSum15(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());
    sum16 = getSum16(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());
    sum18 = getSum18((yearstr) + (et7.getText().toString() + et8.getText().toString()));
    sum19 = getSum19((monthstr) + (sum18));
    sum20 = getSum20((daystr) + sum19);
    sum21 = getMissingNo(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());

    //Destiny Numberkarmic debt
    kar1 = getKar1(et1.getText().toString());
    kar2 = getKar2(et2.getText().toString());
    kar3 = getKar3(et3.getText().toString());
    kar7 = getKar7(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());
    //Heart Number karmic debt
    kar4 = getKar4(et1.getText().toString());
    kar5 = getKar5(et2.getText().toString());
    kar6 = getKar6(et3.getText().toString());
    kar8 = getKar8(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());
    //Talent Number Karmic Debt
    //kar9 = getKar9(et7.getText().toString());

    kar10 = getKar10(et9.getText().toString());
    kar11 = getKar11(et7.getText().toString() + et8.getText().toString() + et9.getText().toString());

    //Personality Number karmic Debt

    kar12 = getKar12(et1.getText().toString());
    kar13 = getKar13(et2.getText().toString());
    kar14 = getKar14(et3.getText().toString());
    kar15 = getKar15(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());

    //Minor Expression Number Karmic Debt Calculation

    kar16 = getKar16(et4.getText().toString());
    kar17 = getKar17(et5.getText().toString());
    kar18 = getKar18(et6.getText().toString());
    kar19 = getKar19(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());

    //Minor Heart Desire Number karmic debt
    kar20 = getKar20(et4.getText().toString());
    kar21 = getKar21(et5.getText().toString());
    kar22 = getKar22(et6.getText().toString());
    kar23 = getKar23(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());

    //Minor Personality Number karmic Debt

    kar24 = getKar24(et4.getText().toString());
    kar25 = getKar25(et5.getText().toString());
    kar26 = getKar26(et6.getText().toString());
    kar27 = getKar27(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());

    //First Pinnacle Karmic Debt




    sum70 = getsum70(et7.getText().toString());
    sum80 = getSum80(et8.getText().toString());
    sum90 = getSum90(et9.getText().toString());



    sum10 = getSum10 ((et1.getText().toString()) + (et2.getText().toString()) + (et3.getText().toString()));
    pin1  = getSumpin1(Integer.toString((int)sum70) + Integer.toString((int) sum80));
    pin2  = getSumpin2(Integer.toString((int)sum70) + Integer.toString((int)sum90));
    pin3  = getSumpin3(Integer.toString((int)pin1) + Integer.toString((int)pin2));
    pin4  = getSumpin4(Integer.toString((int)sum80) + Integer.toString((int)sum90));


    String firstName     = et1.getText().toString();
    String middleName    = et2.getText().toString();
    String lastName      = et3.getText().toString();
    String callFirstName = et4.getText().toString();
    String dates         = et7.getText().toString();
    String months        = et8.getText().toString();
    String years         = et9.getText().toString();

    String aChar3 = "";



    if(firstName.trim().length()>0)

       {
        aChar3 = firstName.substring(0,1);
       }

    String aChar4 = "";

    if(middleName.trim().length()>0)

       {
        aChar4 = middleName.substring(0,1);
       }

    String aChar5 = "";

    if (lastName.trim().length()>0)

       {
        aChar5 = lastName.substring(0,1);
       }







    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(aChar3);
    sb.append(aChar4);
    sb.append(aChar5);
    String aChar6 = sb.toString();
    sum22 = getSum22(String.valueOf(aChar6));
    //Balance Number Karmic Debt
    kar28 = getKar28(String.valueOf(aChar6));

    char aChar = firstName.charAt(0);
    int strLength = firstName.length();
    char aChar1 = firstName.charAt(strLength-1);
    char aChar2 = gReport1(V);                        // Please check here ..I think the problem s here
    int itemCount =9 - sum21.size();


    sum23 = getSum23(String.valueOf(aChar1));
    sum24 = getSum24(String.valueOf(aChar));
    sum25 = getSum25(String.valueOf(aChar2));

    //GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    //int yearat = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);


    int day1 = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
    int month1 = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
    int year1 = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());



   String s1 = String.valueOf(FullExplanationEntry.this.getAge(year1, month1, day1));






    int val = 0;
    long val1  = sum11;
    //long val   = sum16;
    val = Integer.valueOf(s1);
    long val2  = 36 - val1;
    int val4   = 9;

    long val5  = val2 + val4;

    long val6  = val5 + val4;

    long val7  = val6 + 80;


    long val18 = val2 + 1;
    long val19 = val5 + 1;
    long val20 = val6 + 1;

    long pYear = 0;




    if (sum70 > sum80)
    {
        ch1 = (sum70 - sum80);
    }
    else
    {
        ch1 = (sum80 - sum70);
    }

    if (sum70 > sum90)
    {
        ch2 = (sum70 - sum90);
    }
    else
    {
        ch2 = (sum90 - sum70);
    }

    if (sum80 > sum90)
    {
        ch4 = (sum80 - sum90);
    }
    else
    {
        ch4 = (sum90 - sum80);
    }

    if (ch1 > ch2)
    {
        ch3 = ch1 - ch2;
    }
    else
    {
        ch3 = ch2 - ch1;
    }



    if (val <= val2)
    {
        ch = ch1;
    }


    else if ((val > val2) && (val <= val5))
    {
        ch = ch2;
    }

    else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val <= val6))
    {
        ch = ch3;
    }

    else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val > val6) && (val<= val7))
    {
        ch = ch4;
    }


    if (val <= val2)
    {
        pin = pin1;
    }


    else if ((val > val2) && (val <= val5))
    {
        pin = pin2;
    }

    else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val <= val6))
    {
        pin = pin3;
    }

    else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val > val6) && (val<= val7))
    {
        pin = pin4;
    }


    if (sum11 > sum10)
    {
        br1 = sum11 - sum10;
    }
    else
    {
        br1 = sum10 - sum11;
    }
    if(sum12 > sum13)
    {
        br2 = sum12 - sum13;
    }
    else
    {
        br2 = sum13 - sum12;
    }
    if(sum10 > sum12)
    {
        br3 = sum10 - sum12;
    }
    else
    {
        br3 = sum12 - sum10;
    }

    int dayS = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
    int monthS = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
    int yearS = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());
    yearnow = getSumYear(String.valueOf(yearat));
    monthnow = getSumMonth(String.valueOf(monthat));
    daynow = getSumDay(String.valueOf(dayat));
    //pYear = getKarPyar(String.valueOf(yearat));
    //Karmic Debt Pinnacle
    int karPin1 = 0;
    long karPin2 = 0;
    long karPin3 = 0;
    int karPin4 = 0;
    //Karmic day
    int karDay = 0;
    long karYear = 0;
    //Karmic Debt Personal Year
    long karPyr = 0;
    long karPmn = 0;
    long karPdy = 0;
    int kPin1 = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
    long kPin2 = sum9 + Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
    long kPin3 = pin1 + pin2;
    long kPin4 = sum9 + Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
    long kPyr = yearnow + kPin1;
    long kPmn = monthnow + kPyr;
    long kPdy = daynow + kPmn;
    karYear = getKarYear(String.valueOf(yearnow));


    //Karmic Debt First Pinnacle
    if(kPin1 == 13)
    {
        karPin1 = 13;
    }
    else if(kPin1 == 14)
    {
        karPin1 = 14;
    }
    else if(kPin1 == 16)
    {
        karPin1 = 16;
    }
    else if(kPin1 == 19)
    {
        karPin1 = 19;
    }
    else
    {
        karPin1 = 0;
    }
    //Karmic Debt Pinnacle 2
    if(kPin2 == 13)
    {
        karPin2 = 13;
    }
    else if(kPin2 == 14)
    {
        karPin2 = 14;
    }
    else if(kPin2 == 16)
    {
        karPin2 = 16;
    }
    else if(kPin2 == 19)
    {
        karPin2 = 19;
    }
    else
    {
        karPin2 = 0;
    }
    //Karmic Debt Pinnacle 3
    if(kPin3 == 13)
    {
        karPin3 = 13;
    }
    else if(kPin3 == 14)
    {
        karPin3 = 14;
    }
    else if(kPin3 == 16)
    {
        karPin3 = 16;
    }
    else if(kPin3 == 19)
    {
        karPin3 = 19;
    }
    else
    {
        karPin3 = 0;
    }
  //Karmic Debt Pinnacle 4
    if(kPin4 == 13)
    {
        karPin4 = 13;
    }
    else if(kPin4 == 14)
    {
        karPin4 = 14;
    }
    else if(kPin4 == 16)
    {
        karPin4 = 16;
    }
    else if(kPin4 == 19)
    {
        karPin4 = 19;
    }
    else
    {
        karPin4 = 0;
    }
  //Karmic Debt Personal Year No
    if(kPyr == 13)
    {
        karPyr = 13;
    }
    else if(kPyr == 14)
    {
        karPyr = 14;
    }
    else if(kPyr == 16)
    {
        karPyr = 16;
    }
    else if(kPyr == 19)
    {
        karPyr = 19;
    }
    else
    {
        karPyr = 0;
    }
  //Karmic Debt Personal Month No
    if(kPmn == 13)
    {
        karPmn = 13;
    }
    else if(kPmn == 14)
    {
        karPmn = 14;
    }
    else if(kPmn == 16)
    {
        karPmn = 16;
    }
    else if(kPmn == 19)
    {
        karPmn = 19;
    }
    else
    {
        karPmn = 0;
    }
  //Karmic Debt Personal Day No
    if(kPdy == 13)
    {
        karPdy = 13;
    }
    else if(kPdy == 14)
    {
        karPdy = 14;
    }
    else if(kPdy == 16)
    {
        karPdy = 16;
    }
    else if(kPdy== 19)
    {
        karPdy = 19;
    }
    else
    {
        karPdy = 0;
    }
  //Karmic Debt day
    if(dayS == 13)
    {
        karDay = 13;
    }
    else if(dayS == 14)
    {
        karDay = 14;
    }
    else if(dayS == 16)
    {
        karDay = 16;
    }
    else if(dayS == 19)
    {
        karDay = 19;
    }
    else
    {
        karDay = 0;
    }




    if(firstName.equals(""))
    {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Name should not be left blank.. Please enter your First Name and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
    }

    else if(lastName.equals(""))
    {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Last Name should not be left blank.. Please enter your Last Name and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
    }

    else if(callFirstName.equals(""))
    {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your First Name that is currently used and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
    }





    else
    {   


        /*SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editors = setting.edit();
        editors.putString("log", "log");
        editors.commit();*/




         SharedPreferences setting = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editors = setting.edit();
         editors.putString("log", "log");

        // editors.putLong("name18",sum18);
        // editors.putLong("name19",sum19);
        // editors.putLong("name20",sum20);
        // editors.putLong("pin",pin);
        // editors.putLong("ch",ch);
        // editors.putString("log", "log");
        // editors.putString("yearstr",yearstr);
        // editors.putString("monthstr",monthstr);
        // editors.putString("daystr",daystr);

         editors.commit();



        Intent i = new Intent(FullExplanationEntry.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
      //Intent i = new Intent(this, FullExplanation.class);
      //Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondResult.class);



        //Personal Year
        i.putExtra("name18",sum18 + "");
        //Personal Month
        i.putExtra("name19",sum19 + "");
        //Personal Dya
        i.putExtra("name20",sum20 + "");
        //Current Pinnacle
        i.putExtra("pin", pin + "");
        //Current Challenge
        i.putExtra("ch", ch + "");

        i.putExtra("yearstr", yearstr);
        i.putExtra("monthstr", monthstr);
        i.putExtra("daystr", daystr);



        startActivity(i);





/*  int day = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
    int month = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());



   String s = String.valueOf(FullExplanationEntry.this.getAge(year, month, day));

    int age = getAge(year, month, day);
   // int sum17 = getSum17(firstName, age);



             //Destiny number
            i.putExtra("name10", sum10 + "");
            //Telent Number
            i.putExtra("name11", sum11 + "");
            //Heart Desire Number
            i.putExtra("name12", sum12 + "");
            //Personality Number
            i.putExtra("name13", sum13 + "");
            //Minor Expression Number
            i.putExtra("name14", sum14 + "");
            //Minor Heart Desire Number
            i.putExtra("name15", sum15 + "");
            //Minor Personality Number
            i.putExtra("name16", sum16 + "");
            i.putExtra("name17", sum17 + "");
            //First Challenge
            i.putExtra("val2", val2 + "");
            //Second Challenge
            i.putExtra("val5", val5 + "");
            //Thiurd Challenge
            i.putExtra("val6", val6 + "");
            //Fourth Challenge
            i.putExtra("val7", val7 + "");
            i.putExtra("val18", val18 + "");
            i.putExtra("val19", val19 + "");
            i.putExtra("val20", val20 + "");
            i.putExtra("name17", sum17 + "");
            //Current Challenge
            i.putExtra("ch", ch + "");
            //Challenge Numbers
            i.putExtra("ch1", ch1 + "");
            i.putExtra("ch2", ch2 + "");
            i.putExtra("ch3", ch3 + "");
            i.putExtra("ch4", ch4 + "");
            //age
            i.putExtra("a", s + "");
            //Pinnacle
            //First Pinnacle
            i.putExtra("namepin1", pin1 + "");
            //Second Pinnacle
            i.putExtra("namepin2", pin2 + "");
            //Third Pinnacle
            i.putExtra("namepin3", pin3 + "");
            //Fourth Pinnacle
            i.putExtra("namepin4", pin4 + "");
            //Current Pinnacle
            i.putExtra("pin", pin + "");
            //Special Letters
            i.putExtra("aChar", aChar + "");
            i.putExtra("aChar1", aChar1 + "");
            i.putExtra("aChar2",aChar2+ "");
            //Bridge Numbers.
            i.putExtra("br1", br1 + "");
            i.putExtra("br2", br2+ "");
            i.putExtra("br3",br3+ "");
            //Relational Thought  Number
            i.putExtra("name1",sum1 + "");
            //Personal Year Number
            i.putExtra("name18",sum18 + "");
            //Personal Month Number
            i.putExtra("name19",sum19 + "");
            //Personal Day Number
            i.putExtra("name20",sum20 + "");
            //Relational thought Number
            i.putExtra("itemCount",itemCount + "");
            //Karmic Lessonbs
            i.putIntegerArrayListExtra("sum21", (ArrayList<Integer>) sum21);
            // Balance Number
            i.putExtra("name22",sum22 + "");
            //Cap Stone
            i.putExtra("name23",sum23 + "");
            //Corner Stone
            i.putExtra("name24",sum24 + "");
            //First vowel
            i.putExtra("name25",sum25 + "");
            //Destiny number karmic debt FML Full
            i.putExtra("karmi1",kar1 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi2",kar2 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi3",kar3 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi7",kar7 + "");
            //Heart Number Karmic Debt FML Full
            i.putExtra("karmi4",kar4 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi5",kar5 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi6",kar6 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi8",kar8 + "");
            //Talent Number Karmic Debt DY Full
            //i.putExtra("kar9",kar9 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi10",kar10 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi11",kar11 + "");
            //Personality Number Karmic Debt FML Full
          //Heart Number Karmic Debt FML Full
            i.putExtra("karmi12",kar12 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi13",kar13 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi14",kar14 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi15",kar15 + "");
          //Minor Expression Number Karmic Debt FML Full
            i.putExtra("karmi16",kar16 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi17",kar17 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi18",kar18 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi19",kar19 + "");
          //Minor Heart Desire Number Karmic Debt FML Full
            i.putExtra("karmi20",kar20 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi21",kar21 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi22",kar22 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi23",kar23 + "");
          //Minor Personality Number Karmic Debt FML Full
            i.putExtra("karmi24",kar24 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi25",kar25 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi26",kar26 + "");
            i.putExtra("karmi27",kar27 + "");
            //Balance Number Karmic Debt
            i.putExtra("karmi28",kar28 + "");
            //Birth Day Karmic Debt
            i.putExtra("karPin1",karPin1 + "");
            i.putExtra("karPin2",karPin2 + "");
            i.putExtra("karPin3",karPin3 + "");
            i.putExtra("karPin4",karPin4 + "");
            //Persobnal year karmic debt
            //Personal year Karmic Debt
            i.putExtra("karPyr",karPyr + "");
            //Personal Month Karmic Debt 
            i.putExtra("karPmn",karPmn + "");
            //Karmic Debt Personal Day
            i.putExtra("karPdy",karPdy + "");
            //Current day Karmic Debt
            i.putExtra("karDay",karDay + "");
            //Current Universla Year
            i.putExtra("karyr29",karYear + "");


           // startActivity(i);*/



    }



}
    }
```

Comment: nobody here to help me

Comment: What exactly do you understand by "activating a View"?

Comment: I mean to call a method from another method

Comment: You need to post all the relevant code for us to give you a correct answer. You call a method the same way whether you are inside another method or not. Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call it like this

```
SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
if (setting.getString("log", "").toString().equals("log")) {
    // someView is just an example of a view's id. You will need to change that
    // to the id of the view you want to go into your save method.
    // The id is defined in your xml file. 
    View v = findViewById(R.id.someView);
    save(v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. can you please tell me what is this someView...?

Comment: Your method `save` takes a view as a parameter. I used `someView` as just an example. You would have to pass in whatever view you want to go into the `save` method.

Comment: I updated the code can you please check..

Comment: Ok, your `save` method doesn't even use the view parameter that you defined, you can completely remove it. I will update my answer to match your code.

Comment: sorry Takendarkk... I am using a View V inside this method... char aChar2 = gReport1(V); and I think .. that makes problem..

Comment: please check now thats my mistake... actually it is a lengthy code thats y ..I didn't post..

Comment: can you please post it once again

Comment: thanks... sure... I will accept your answer

Comment: If you have more problems just leave a comment and I can come back in the morning.